# How I can load data from xml into database using php code?

Tags: database, insert

I am beginner. I want to load data from xml into a database table. My target is point out in below,

1. Setup a connection to any pre-defined MySQL database.
2. Remove all the rows from the table in_rank_raw where handled_date in not empty and commit.
3. Check if in_rank_raw is empty. If so, report and exit.
4. Finds the latest dated x.xml file from pre-defined path on the server.
5. Read the x.xml file data and insert the rows into the table in_rank_raw and commit.
6. Move the x.xml file to another place (pre-defined path).
7. Report that the information has been imported successfully and exit.

   ```
   Here is an example of xml file(name: x.xml)  :




   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Caphyon/Advanced%20Web%20Ranking/transforms/exportrank/exportrankdata.xsd">
       <header><col>Date</col><col>Search Engine</col><col>Keyword</col><col>Website</col><col>Page Rank</col><col>Alexa Rank</col><col>Position</col><col>Previous</col><col>Change</col><col>Best</col><col>Page</col><col>Result Type</col></header>
       <row><cell><val>2013-03-11</val></cell><cell><val>Bing MSN</val></cell><cell><val>latest news</val></cell><cell><val>http://www.cnn.com</val></cell><cell><googlerank><rank><position>9</position><previous>-1</previous><lastdate>-1</lastdate></rank></googlerank></cell><cell><alexarank><rank><position>31</position><previous>-1</previous><lastdate>-1</lastdate></rank></alexarank></cell><cell><val>4</val></cell><cell><val>-</val></cell><cell><val>+</val></cell><cell><val>2</val></cell><cell><val>1</val></cell></row>
       <row><cell><val>2013-03-11</val></cell><cell><val>Google</val></cell><cell><val>sport news</val></cell><cell><val>http://espn.go.com</val></cell><cell><googlerank><rank><position>8</position><previous>-1</previous><lastdate>-1</lastdate></rank></googlerank></cell><cell><alexarank><rank><position>28</position><previous>-1</previous><lastdate>-1</lastdate></rank></alexarank></cell><cell><val>6</val></cell><cell><val>-</val></cell><cell><val>+</val></cell><cell><val>1</val></cell><cell><val>1</val></cell></row>
   </data>
   ```

   Please help me to start analysing on your code. Thank you.